# More Accurate Average - InfluxDB/Grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana

This might be a little hard to explain... but I'll do my best.

I'm wanting to calculate an accurate average in grafana using data that a number of computers that changes over time...

For example, i am keeping track of how often a computer goes offline. This value always changes, however the computer name always says the same.

My problem is, is that if my timestamp changes, Grafana sees this as another device (so to speak) which means it adds the same computer twice...

```
E.g
First dataset:
C1 = 5
C2 = 10
C3 = 15
C4 = 20

Average = 50/4 = 12.5
```

However lets say C4 goes off again. Grafana not only takes 20 but also the new value of 21.

```
C1 = 5
C2 = 10
C3 = 15
C4 = 21

Grafana Average = 14.2
Real Average = 51/4 = 12.75
```

Does anyone know away around this (without keeping the timestamp constant) and thus over writing the previous value of the "Offline" value.

Its occurred to me that this also has something to do with Influx DB with the average request, so if the correct value can be returned there, then that would be great.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "if my timestamp changes"? And, just few sentences away - "without keeping the timestamp constant"... what do you mean by "timestamp constant"?

Comment: When i input the data i can insert a unix timestamp, this timestamp can be the actual time, or i can insert the data with a set timestamp, for example: If i keep the timestamp at the first of the month of the first our so 1/2/2018 1:00:00 (unix timestamp: 1517965200000) then the value stored there will constantly be overwritten. Thus giving me an accurate average. However if I change that and the timestamp changes depending on what the time currently is, then it gives me an inaccurate average because the average request counts it as another value.